# How to get the error code from a QProcess?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qprocess

I have a function `A()` in which I execute eight other 'sub-functions' which all include a `QProcess`. How do I get the return codes from all the QProcesses?

Example:

```
void Mainclass::A()
{
    B();
    C();
    // ...
    I();
}

void Mainclass::B() 
{
    QString CommandPath = "PathB";
    QProcess *Process = new QProcess(this);

    Process->setWorkingDirectory(MainDir);
    Process->setStandardOutputFile(MainDir + "/geometries");
    Process->start(CommandPath);
    Process->waitForFinished();
    QProcess::ExitStatus Status = Process->exitStatus(); 

    if (Status == 0)
    {
       std::cout << "App executed!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I found [this example](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/13948-Standard-error-and-standard-output-from-QProcess-in-wrong-order) but don't understand how to implement it myself because I use pointer objects in my application.

Comment: I think there should be an exitcode member variable in the QProcess class.... do you see anything like Process->exitCode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe `int QProcess::exitCode () const`? [See](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#exitCode).